# check statement add constraint

Tags: sql

create table sallaary(

```
E_ID  number (10) ,

bank_type varchar(10),

creditcardnumber number(12) primary key  ,

 bonus number(5),

 salary_date date ,

 work_hours number (3),

 constraint check_hours check (work_hours > 40 ) 

constraint sallary2_emp_fk foreign key (E_ID) references salloonee_employee1
```

);

Now, this is my code. The idea of the first constraint "check_hours " is to add a bonus to the employee if his work hours exceeded 40 hours but I don't know how to write it

Note: the first constraint "check_hours " is not complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want a `bonus` when the hours exceeds 40.  If so:

```
constraint check_hours check (not (bonus = 0 and work_hours > 40))
```

Or equivalently:

```
constraint check_hours check (bonus > 0 or work_hours <= 40)
```

Or, if `bonus` can be `NULL`:

```
constraint check_hours check (not (coalesce(bonus, 0) = 0 and work_hours > 40))
```

Comment: can I write it without the "not "?

Comment: @yuki . . . Yes, but the `not` version is closer to how you would express the condition.

Comment: What I understood from the code that you wrote is that if the bonus is not equal to zero and the hours are not greater than 40, is it correct?

Comment: If the bonus is zero and the hours are greater than 40, then the row is not accepted, because in that case, the bonus should have a value.